# 404 Code for Traefik and Portainer in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, ansible, traefik, portainer

I am trying to setup Traefik with Portainer on a Docker Swarm and run it with Terraform and Ansible. I am new to this type of thing and this is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow so help would be greatly appreciated. Essentially, once I use Terraform to apply the Ansible playbooks to my server, I try to go to the IP for it and to go to the actual domain to test if either of them work. So far only the "whoami" one works at https://test.domain.name/whoami but none of the others work, not event he dashboard for Traefik and I can not understand why.

this is the traefik-stack.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--log=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" #comment out when done
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true" #change to false when done
      - "--api.dashboard=true" #change to false when done
      - "--api.debug=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.network=dev"
      - "--providers.docker.useBindPortIP=true"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web-secure.http.tls=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web-secure.http.tls.domains=domain.name"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/opt/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
      - "/opt/certificates:/certificates"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule = PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
        # Dummy service for Swarm port detection. The port can be any valid integer value.
        - "traefik.http.services.dummy-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999"

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    networks:
      - dev
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Path(`/whoami`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true" #if active, whoami works on HTTPS, if off then works on http

networks:
  dev:
    external: true
```

this is the portainer-agent-stack.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - agent_network
      - dev
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - agent_network
      - dev
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=PathPrefix(`/portainer`)"
        - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"

networks:
  agent_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
  dev:
    external: true

volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

and this is the traefik.toml:

```
################################################################
#
# Configuration sample for Traefik v2.
#
# For Traefik v1: https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/v1.7/traefik.sample.toml
#
################################################################

################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################
[global]
  checkNewVersion = true
  sendAnonymousUsage = true

################################################################
# Entrypoints configuration
################################################################

# Entrypoints definition
#
# Optional
# Default:
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.web-secure]
    address = ":443"

################################################################
# Traefik logs configuration
################################################################

# Traefik logs
# Enabled by default and log to stdout
#
# Optional
#
[log]

  # Log level
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "ERROR"
  #
  level = "DEBUG"

  # Sets the filepath for the traefik log. If not specified, stdout will be used.
  # Intermediate directories are created if necessary.
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: os.Stdout
  #
  # filePath = "log/traefik.log"

  # Format is either "json" or "common".
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "common"
  #
  # format = "json"

################################################################
# Access logs configuration
################################################################

# Enable access logs
# By default it will write to stdout and produce logs in the textual
# Common Log Format (CLF), extended with additional fields.
#
# Optional
#
[accessLog]

  # Sets the file path for the access log. If not specified, stdout will be used.
  # Intermediate directories are created if necessary.
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: os.Stdout
  #
  # filePath = "/path/to/log/log.txt"

  # Format is either "json" or "common".
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "common"
  #
  # format = "json"

################################################################
# API and dashboard configuration
################################################################

# Enable API and dashboard
[api]

  # Enable the API in insecure mode
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: false
  #
  # insecure = true

  # Enabled Dashboard
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: true
  #
  # dashboard = false

################################################################
# Ping configuration
################################################################

# Enable ping
[ping]

  # Name of the related entry point
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "traefik"
  #
  # entryPoint = "traefik"

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################

# Enable Docker configuration backend
[providers.docker]

  # Docker server endpoint. Can be a tcp or a unix socket endpoint.
  #
  # Required
  # Default: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  #
  # endpoint = "tcp://10.10.10.10:2375"

  # Default host rule.
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)"
  #
  # defaultRule = "Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}.docker.localhost`)"

  # Expose containers by default in traefik
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: true
  #
  # exposedByDefault = false

[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile="/certificates/domain.name.cert"
  keyFile="/certificates/domain.name.key"
```

I know the Portainer and Portainer Agent works because they worked fine before trying to add Traefik, so my hunch is that I did something wrong in the Traefik or something is weird about Traefik and Docker Swarm working together. The Terraform applies with no failures and there are no errors when it is running, so I can;t understand why only the whoami works and doesn't return a 404. Let me know if more information is needed and sorry for it being so long.